# Enchant.js collision detection occuring after removeChild

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, collision, removechild

I'm currently working on a game using enchant.js as the game engine and I'm trying make it where if the player sprite and enemy sprite collide, the enemy sprite gets removed and the code that detected collision doesn't execute anymore. The problem is that after removing the enemy sprite, the code is still executing. Here's the game on a web server. If you open the console, you can see it spamming "hit" after the enemy is removed (and if you stay in the spot the enemy was previously in).
http://people.ucsc.edu/~kcilia/dainty_knight/

```
//Executes code every frame
game.addEventListener('enterframe', function() {
    //detects whether player sprite is within 40
    //pixels of the enemy sprite
    if(knight.within(enemy,40)){
        //prints "hit" if collision is successful
        console.log("hit");
        //removes enemy sprite if collision is successful
        scene.removeChild(enemy);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem but made the enemy into a class and put the within/intersect listener + removal on the enemy instead and it worked.